# Periodic updates of an object in Unity

Tags: unity, timer

I'm trying to make a collider appear every 1 second.  But I can't get the code right.  I tried enabling the collider in the Update function and putting a yield to make it update every second or so.  But it's not working (it gives me an error: ***Update() cannot be a coroutine.***)

How would I fix this?  Would I need a timer system to toggle the collider?

```
var waitTime    : float = 1;
var trigger     : boolean = false;

function Update () {

        if(!trigger){
            collider.enabled = false;
            yield WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        }
        if(trigger){
            collider.enabled = true;
            yield WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't use a coroutine in the Update function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be rather simple. Just have an accumulator where you add the elapsed time each frame. As soon as the accumulator is greater or equal to your "waitTime", toggle the collider.

Example:

```
var accumulator:float = 0.0;
var waitTime:float = 1.0;

function Update(){
    accumulator += Time.deltaTime;
    if(accumulator >= waitTime){
        // change enabled from true to false and vice-versa.
        collider.enabled = !collider.enabled;
        accumulator -= waitTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I delay the start-up of the object with the code?  I tried adding another variable to waitTime but it didn't work.

Comment: @Blue You could set `waitTime` to `10.0` initially, then set it to `1.0` in the `if` block (*after* `accumulator -= waitTime;`)